# No devices connected... Waiting for devices to be connected

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, turtlebot, libopenni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I start 3dsensor.launch I get:

```
[ INFO] [1414430559.252574176]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

When I rosrun **openni_camera openni_node** by itself I get the same error.

I've trawled rosanswers looking for a solution, but nothing's worked yet. : C
**lsusb** lists the kinect; I've followed the suggestions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/67876/no-kinect-connectedwaiting-for-devices-to-be-connected/), and the suggestions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/109411/asus-xtion-problems-with-ubuntu-1204-running-ros-fuerte/), and the suggestions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35020/no-devices-connected/), and the suggestions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38991/no-device-connected-turtlebot-kinect/), and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/121326/openni-no-device-connected-kinect/) to no avail.

This is being run on a turtlebot2, and both the turtlebot and the workstation are on 14.04 trusty and indigo igloo. The kinect is plugged into the usb 2.0 port.

lsusb yields:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:5605 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:883e Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Turtlebot specs are:
Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty
Memory 1.8 G
Processor Intel Celeron @ 1.50Ghz
Graphics intel ivybridge mobile
OS type 64 bit

I'm at a loss. does anyone have suggestions?

I'm not entirely certain if it's related, but when I start up my minimal launch I get this:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.20.11.86:11311
core service [/rosout] found
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [12734]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-2]: started with pid [12760]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3]: started with pid [12835]
process[mobile_base-4]: started with pid [12854]
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [12976]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [13040]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-7]: started with pid [13081]
process[capability_server-8]: started with pid [13098]
process[app_manager-9]: started with pid [13105]
process[master-10]: started with pid [13145]
process[interactions-11]: started with pid [13187]
process[zeroconf/zeroconf-12]: started with pid [13232]
[ INFO] [1414430339.909748537]: Zeroconf: service successfully established [turtlebot][_ros-master._tcp][11311]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.195425] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/xbox360_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/xbox360_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.196079] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/map_manager'.  'turtlebot_rapps/map_manager' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.196588] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/follower'.  'turtlebot_rapps/follower' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.197078] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/map_nav'.  'turtlebot_rapps/map_nav' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.197499] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/3dsensor'.  'turtlebot_rapps/3dsensor' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.197939] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/ps3_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/ps3_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.198351] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/video_teleop'.  'turtlebot_rapps/video_teleop' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.198807] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/make_a_map'.  'turtlebot_rapps/make_a_map' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.199216] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/listener'.  'rocon_apps/listener' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.199630] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/panorama'.  'turtlebot_rapps/panorama' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.200104] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/chirp'.  'rocon_apps/meow_chirp' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.200580] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'turtlebot_rapps/auto_docking'.  'turtlebot_rapps/auto_docking' has been selected.
[WARN] [WallTime: 1414430344.201012] Rapp Manager : No preferred rapp for 'rocon_apps/talker'.  'rocon_apps/talker' has been selected.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196035/no-devices-connected...-waiting-for-devices-to-be-connected/) by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-10-27**:
What do you get from lsusb? and how did you start kinect? what's your pc spec?

**Comment by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) on 2014-10-28**:\

- I've updated the question with the contents of lsusb.
- The kinect is listed there, as it should. I started the kinect by making sure everything is connected. All the lights are green.
- Which computer do you want the specs for, the workstation or the turtlebot?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-10-29**:
turtlebot's spec would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out the solution was to get an [openni patch](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect). This resolved the connection error.

However, I now have a minor issue with RVIZ.

From the 3d Launch I get:

```
[ WARN] [1414934636.270421799]: Camera calibration file /home/turtlebot/.ros/camera_info/depth_0000000000000000.yaml not found. 
[ WARN] [1414934636.270594235]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

**rostopic echo camera/depth_registered/image_raw** produces numbers, and I get a point-cloud visualization.

---

Originally posted by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) with karma: 41 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lokus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20953/lokus/) on 2014-11-26**:
i've the same problem but im getting the openni drivers from apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-camera and ..-launch and executing roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch. What do you mean with "getting an openni patch"? Are you installing those drivers from git before indigo's openni packages?

**Comment by [Kongaloosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20476/kongaloosh/) on 2014-11-29**:
@lokus, That's where you should be getting them. As far as I know, openni actually doesn't support the Kinect. The patch which I linked to fixes this. I didn't have to remove and re-install anything, I just downloaded it alongside my existing stack.

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-16**:
hey can you plz tell me how can i download and use "https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect" or [openni patch](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect)" on ros? i am new to linux and ros and i am facing the same above mentioned problem for kinect.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

disabling USB3.0 on BIOS should work on openni_launch,

http://answers.ros.org/question/115581/my-kinetic-camera-stop-working-no-device-detected/
http://answers.ros.org/question/202836/no-devices-connected/

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benwex93](https://answers.ros.org/users/38364/benwex93/) on 2020-06-20**:
lspci -nn | grep USB | cut -d '[' -f3 | cut -d ']' -f1 | xargs -I@ setpci -H1 -d @ d0.l=0

from: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux/